# Python function's return type is a function?

Tags: python

```
def func(input: str) -> int: _another_func(input)
   // ...
   // returns some int

def _another_func(input: str) -> None
  if (input == "abc"):
    raise Exception
```

What does it mean to have the return type as a function in this case, and that function has no dependency on the actual return results, but instead depends on an input of the parent function? When _another_func() get run ?

Comment: so 'int' here as a return type is meaningless? is it overridden by _another_func ?

Answer (score 0):

It just shows which data type should be returned in this case int.
_another_func(input) should be in new line.
But if you'll try to return another data type it'll also work.
It's just to make maintenance/code review/life easier.